# My multithreading breaks up my list of integers into single numbers

Tags: python, dataframe, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have a list of 9 digit integers I'm trying to run through a function to take all of the 'good' policies and append them to another list.  I'm new to multithreading and when I use it, the number of unique integers goes from 410,136 to 3,334,192.

For some reason, when I send it through the multithreading pool, it breaks up each 9 digit integer into single digits.

This is the function:

```
record_id = df_tabular['policy'].unique().astype('str')

def build_safe_list(list_id):
    for record_i in list_id:
        try:
            int_record = int(record_i)
            safe_record_id_list.append(int_record)
            #print(record_i)
        except:
            #print(record_i)
            bad_record_id.append(record_i)

#build_safe_list(record_id)
```

When I run this without `build_safe_list(record_id)` commented out, it does fine.

When I run the below however, it messes up like described above:

```
safe_record_id_list = []
bad_record_id = []

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
num_thread = 16
pool = ThreadPool(num_thread)
results = pool.imap_unordered(build_safe_list, record_id)
```

Comment: Rather than passing in a string, then converting to an int in the loop, have you tried passing in `record_id = df_tabular['policy'].unique().astype('int')`? My understanding of multiprocessing is that it pre-chunks the data, which in this case may involve pre-splitting the string into a list of chars to iterate over

Comment: Same issue when I do record_id that way.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. The build_safe_list function doesn't return anything. Are you expecting good policies in safe_record_id_list?
One problem that is breaking up your "list_id" is that the parameter being passed to build_safe_list() is a string, and it is iterating over each char in that string. Why are you iterating over "list_id" ?

Comment: How is `record_id` defined? Like @Sandip I suspect it is a string rather than a list. Iterating over a string returns individual characters. Which sort of matches the description of your problem.